# How to restrict plugin to the page it was created at

Tags: django, django-cms

I have created a django cms plugin by extending CMSPluginBase,
however when I add it to a page it shows up as a suggestion on all other pages too. For example if I have an image plugin and I add it to a page i dont want to see that image show up on all the other pages.

I cant find anyway to bind a plugin to the page it was created at in docs.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are generic, the whole point is that by default you can add them anywhere because as you build pages where they may provide features or functionality required. However you can restrict plugins that can appear within a placeholder using the `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF` setting.

Therefore the simple solution would be to define all of your placeholders & what plugins you allow in them using `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF`. For example;

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'audio': {
        'plugins': ['AudioPlugin', ],
        'name': gettext("Audio"),
    },
    'content': {
        'plugins': [
            'LinkPlugin', 'TextPlugin',
        ],
        'text_only_plugins': [
            'AudioTextPlugin', 'FilePlugin', 'LinkPlugin', 'QuoteTextPlugin',
            'VideoTextPlugin'
        ],
        'name': gettext("Content"),
    },
    'gallery': {
        'plugins': ['ImageGalleryCMSPlugin', ],
        'name': gettext("Image galleries"),
    }
}
```

Then you can create a specific template if you want to ensure a certain plugin only appears on a certain page in a certain placeholder.